# Is there an appetite for a longer lasting repository of knowledge here?

Tags: discussion, topic-scope, questions

I am a member of several other established SE boards (under a different login).

The successful boards share the goal of building and maintaining a long-lasting repository of knowledge.

To achieve this, they mark questions off-topic if they are about anything subject to change. This includes questions about specific software and hardware that may come and go and, therefore, be irrelevant to the general population of the board in a few years or even months.

Questions are also marked off-topic if they are speculative ("how might this work?"), shopping-related ("What's the best product for doing X?"), or opinion-based ("what's your favourite way to X?"). These are considered short-term because changing trends will make them irrelevant or even wrong over time.

Questions that survive and do well are those that are aimed at solving specific problems relating directly to the subject matter. For instance, here on Sound Design, questions might include things like mixing sounds in 5:1 or making particular sound textures.

I'm sure that the things I'm suggesting as off-topic would remove a large chunk of content so, to counterbalance that, I'd also like to see so-called 'musical sound design' included as on-topic here as that encroaches heavily on modern cinematic sound design and shares a lot of common goals and elements.

I'd like to know what the appetite is for a more rigorous approach to policing questions in these ways to ensure the longevity of the information here.

Can we affect policy changes that preserve a legacy of good information about the methods, mechanics, and philosophies of sound design rather than simply providing software and hardware support (and who do we need to talk to about that)?

Answer (score 2):

This site has had a turbulent start - it came from a couple of other sites where the rules were not as strict as Stack Exchange, so the population was very subjective, and it was more of a discussion forum.

In the change over, we lost a lot of those skilled and experienced folks, and growth has been challenging ever since - which I think is partly to blame for our preponderance of software questions. Ffmpeg questions we seem to have accepted, but we do close most software and hardware questions, and in fact most of your suggestions are in line with the ones we aim to close.

Here, as with most of the other small sites I moderate, I think we would not necessarily aim to delete posts on specific versions of software, as we know that folks will use all sorts of versions, and until the site is big enough to succeed without those, we should continue to accept them.

Franck’s post is not really accurate - as in general if a post gets no votes, then we can be reasonably confident it is not suited to the site (yes, exceptions exist, but it’s a good rule of thumb) so we encourage the roomba as it helps maintain quality.

Comment: Thanks for a better answer and your correction of Franck's post. I have seen online communities die under similar policies: The specialists you want to attract are not interested in 'which connector' or 'which DAW' questions and either stop interacting or just don't sign up because it's too difficult to get to the good content. On top of that, you're setting up the legacy problem of what happens when you reach your watershed and choose to remove the poor quality content. That's already a mammoth task and it's only going to get bigger as this content attracts more of the same.

Comment: @7zResearch - yeah, for some communities it works really well, and for others it doesn't. Here we already lost the key specialists in that early transition, so it has been hard. We absolutely do welcome your input on this here - this site is slowly growing, but unfortunately too slowly.

Comment: On software, I know people who still use Cubase 4. It came out in 2006. Some very good sound designers and producers use isolated systems running Windows XP because they can't see any reason to upgrade. It does exactly what they want, and they know it very well. I can appreciate that, I'd love to still be on Windows 7 tbh.

Comment: @n00dles - the problem is that "can't see any reason to upgrade" - they need totake into account the really big non-functional requirement of software: that it can be secured. XP cannot be secured. Win 7 is the same now.

Comment: Yeah security would be an issue, but I think they use isolated systems - dedicated solely to whatever it's doing and no internet connection. Maybe a limited LAN connection for data transfers to newer systems. I like that kind of retro setup. Mainly because I dislike newer Windows OSes.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there an appetite for a longer lasting repository of knowledge here?

I don't believe so, since [questions get routinely removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179) just because they haven't received an upvote and an answer. One cannot seriously claim that Stack Exchange is a proper repository for long-lasting knowledge in such precarious conditions.

Comment: Yes, that's the sense that I'm getting for this particular exchange. Over on the UX exchange, there is a real drive to preserve a solid bank of knowledge that is consistently valid over time. The mods are good at taking out any shopping requests, speculative or opinion-based questions to leave just the stuff that will still be valid 5, 10, or 15 years from now. I also understand from reading the meta, that there is a shortage of mods.